# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE got SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE

Tags: java, jms, ojdbc, oracle-aq

With newer version of Oracle DB (12.2.0.1) we start to receive ORA-00932, for the code which works well with older DB server.
Moreover the driver reports strange detail of exception:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE
>   got SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE

you can see the expected and got type names are same.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE got SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4Caqe.doOAQEQ(T4Caqe.java:355)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doEnqueue(T4CConnection.java:3938)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.enqueue(PhysicalConnection.java:10076)
        at oracle.jms.AQjmsProducer.jdbcEnqueue(AQjmsProducer.java:1096)
        ... 13 more
```

Issue is raised from stand alone Java application, using following AQ driver libs:

```
aqapi.jar;javax.jms_1.1.4.jar;jta-1.1.jar
```

Used ojdbc driver version:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.5.0_30-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.3.0
Repository-Id: JAVAVM_11.2.0.3.0_LINUX_110823
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Specification-Version: 4.0
Main-Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
sealed: true
```

Comment: the same issue type is specified on ORA support: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/oracle_database/4154251.html and https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2450300_1.html but without answer or non-public section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we started to use the same jdbc driver version as Oracle DB server:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 12.2.0.1.0
sealed: true
Repository-Id: JAVAVM_12.2.0.1.0_LINUX.X64_161213
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Specification-Title: JDBC
Created-By: 25.91-b14 (Oracle Corporation)
Specification-Version: 4.0
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Main-Class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

AQ JMS driver start to works well. I can't find any Oracle documentation note, that 11.2 jdbc driver is not compatible with 12.2 ORA DB server, even not for AQ JMS implementation (aqapi.jar).

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02 there are no details about Oracle JMS AQ driver